# how to get capacitance value from android phone?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, screen

Current mobile device detects touch event via sensing the capacitance change caused by human finger.

Is there any methods that I can get the raw capacitance value?

It seems that the android API does not provide such interface, but how can I give this data directly from driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research on internet and found an excellent tutorial [here](https://ubicomplab.cs.washington.edu/raincheck/index.html).

Based on this tutorial, I write some scripts to get and visualize raw capacitance data from Samsung Galaxy SII (i9100). The code is available on [my github](https://github.com/hankes-garden/capacitive_screen).

Hope this may help someone who needs to do the same thing.